# ajax + django, random on click button

Tags: javascript, django, ajax

I have a little problem whit using django and ajax.
Haave a code 
views.py

```
def rand(request):
data = {}
action = request.POST.get('action')
if action == 'NeedRandom':
    data['result'] = random.randint(0,1000000)
else:
    data['result'] = 'Error'
return render(request, 'registers/myaction.html', data)
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('myaction/', views.rand, name='my-action'),
]
```

and some one script

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Forming csrf_token
    function getCookie(name) {
        let cookieValue = null;
        if (document.cookie && document.cookie != '') {
            let cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
            for (let i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
                let cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
                // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
                if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) == (name + '=')) {
                    cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return cookieValue;
    };

    let data = {}

    $('.mybutton').on('click', function(e){
        data['action'] = 'NeedRandom';
        data['csrfmiddlewaretoken'] = getCookie('csrftoken');
        SendAjax();
    });

    function SendAjax(){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost:8000/myaction',
            method: 'POST',
            data: data,
            cached: true,
            success: function(data){
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function(e){
                console.log(e);
            }
        })
    }
})
```

And buttom at files myaction.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content%}
   <input type="submit" class="mybutton" value="random number">
{% endblock %}
```

when i click on the button i have at  template page html code, but not random number
why?
who can help me?

Comment: change all your `POST` method to get. Also you don't need a template unless its very necessary. you can use `django.http.HttpResponse`

Comment: @Tushortz ichange all post to get
and use return HttpResponse(data)
Now I see  on the page : "result"

Comment: use `JSONResponse` instead. `JSONResponse(data, safe=False)`

Comment: @Tushortz now i have {"result": "Error"}
error at js now?

Comment: Consider removing type=submit from your input as you are not using a form there

Comment: @OlzhasArystanov did it, nothing has changed
I don’t understand why even the button on the page is not displayed

Comment: Do you want your view to return template or just return your random number in json? Second option seems logical cause you are using AJAX. Therefore, it might be a good idea to switch from `render` to smth like `JsonResponse` in your rand view as @Tushortz already pointed out

Comment: @OlzhasArystanov 
I want to get a random number when I click on the button. But when you go to the page, even the button is not displayed
i change  return render(request, 'registers/myaction.html', data) to  JsonResponse(data, safe=False), but now i see at the page {"result": "Error"}

Comment: It seems that your `else` block is invoked, where you do this: `data['result'] = 'Error'`. The problem is probably on the javascript side here. Django doesn't receive `action` in POST data

Comment: @OlzhasArystanov I understand it. I just can’t understand where. In general, the script should access django when the button is clicked, and not immediately.
And it's kind of spelled out in js